# IE goes haywire with formating other broswers fare fine

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have made a simple page for a sound board that I made. I use Chrome actively and it looks how I would like it. I've tested it in Safari, Firefox, and, Chrome. Here is a picture of the site, at http://nkonecny.com/monkeyislandsb:
[image]

As you can see in IE9 the margin is completely wrong, there is a broken image looking box at the top right, and towards the bottom the second Ad and footer are gone. I would post code but I slightest clue of where the problem lies so I thought it would be easier to direct to my site and view the source. Please let me know if this needs more clarification.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the IE anomolies are a "red herring"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the HTML comment from before the DOCTYPE. Putting anything before the DOCTYPE triggers Quirks Mode in IE.

Also, that broken image thing is coming from your `<img>` tag, whatever that's there for...

Comment: Did you remove that comment? Doesn't look like it to me.

Comment: That fixed the margin and broken image perfectly! But the ad/footer are still not displaying in IE

Comment: It says "Syntax error". This might be because you have `<!--` at the start of your script, but no `// -->` at the end.

Comment: Wow, Awesome eye. I need to practice style, a whole lot. Haha. Thanks!

Comment: Seconded - you have way too many `<center>` tags, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You have a comment before your DTD:

```
<!-- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/05/13/unlocking-the-power-of-html5-lt-audio-gt.aspx -->
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

`<!DOCTYPE html>` must be the *very first thing*, or IE will go into Quirks Mode, i.e. IE6 rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a reset style sheet to ensure that the base styles on all browsers are the same. A good way of doing this is to use normalize.css (http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/), as it doesn't mess around too much.

Looking at your site, it also renders in quirks mode - that's because the first line isn't the doctype, but a comment.